# If the interest rate is constant, then the forward price and the futures price are equal?

Tags: futures, forward

I was going through the proof about the equality of forward and futures price (assuming constant interest rate) in a book. Somewhere, the authors used the fact that suppose we start with two capitals - say A and B and we end up with the same final capital S, then A=B otherwise there will be arbitrage opportunity. Why arbitrage arises if A and B are not same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the forward price equal to the future price?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54628/is-the-forward-price-equal-to-the-future-price)

Comment: I am voting to close this question as I believe it is a duplicate of https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54628/is-the-forward-price-equal-to-the-future-price/54642#54642 . If I am correct in interpreting your question correctly, you are asking about why futures and forward contracts don't always equal in price, if so this question above should hopefully answer.

Answer (score 1):

Say for example A>B.  Then you would sell strategy A versus buying strategy B, collecting A-B initially.  At the end you will have S-S, which is zero.  So you have a risk free profit.